# Trifluoroacetic acid, Formic acid and dichloromethane

Tags: solvents, equipment

I am working in a small lab (in a small company) with very poor conditions, which I have to improve (for example: no sink , I have to wash the glassware in the bathroom). My organic chemistry is very poor, I am new to using solvents, and I have several basic doubts:

1. How to correctly wash the glassware after use?
2. How to correctly dispose of wasted solvents?
3. Should I leave the chemical fume hood on after using it and, if so, for how long?

I basically only do electrospinning here, using the respective solvents:
- Trifluoroacetic acid
- Dichloromethane
- Formic acid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to correctly wash the glassware after use?

The glassware must be rinsed with a non-toxic (or less-toxic) solvent such as acetone or isopropanol before washing to carry over the bulk of hazardous materials.  You should the wash the glassware with soap and water, rinse with water, followed by a rinse with DI water, isopropanol, or ethanol to eliminate water spots.

> How to correctly dispose of wasted solvents?

Your solvents should go into an appropriate waste container and be marked as hazardous waste with the contents listed.  You also need to list the companies EPA number to dispose of the waste.  Have a reputable waste disposal service receive your waste and take it to a disposal facility.

> Should I leave the chemical fume hood on after using it and, if so, for how long?

If anything hazardous is still in the hood you must leave it on. If there is nothing in the hood there is no reason you must leave it running.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it is everything I needed to know! As soon as I get "enough rep to vote" I will come back here to upvote your answer.